What is the basis and the dimension if the resulting system of equation has no free variables?
I was answering this problem:
Find the dimension of, and a basis for, the solution space of the homogeneous system of equations:
$$+−=0$$
$$2+4−=0$$
$$3+2+2=0$$
Then, I converted the given system of equation into matrix form and converted it into its REF:
\begin{bmatrix}1&1&-1\\0&1&\frac{1}{2}\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
From what I know, this denotes that there are no free variables.
The resulting system of equation then became:
$$x+y-z=0$$
$$y+\frac{1}{2}z=0$$
$$z=0$$
where $x=0, y=0, z=0$
Does this mean that the dimension is zero and the basis is an empty set?

It means that the empty set is a basis, but otherwise yes.

Thank you for the answers! I'm sorry for the boldface, I thought it was okay, it's my first time using LaTeX and I was experimenting .

In general, the solution space of a homogeneous system $Ax=0$ with $A\in M_n(K)$ and $r={\rm rank}(A)$ has dimension $n-r$, where $n=r=3$ here in this case. So $\dim V=0$. See this post.
